# Kotlin Function to class

Tags: class, kotlin

can anyone please teach me how to convert a function to class? 
I'm repeatedly using a "Parse Query" function() within my project. i was wondering if i can convert a funtion to a class so i can call it from anywhere?

```
fun queryComment(postid: String, limit: Int, skip: Int, completion: (comment: ArrayList<CommentedUsers>) -> Unit) : ArrayList<CommentedUsers> {

        var countObject: Int
        var sampleArray = ArrayList<CommentedUsers>()
        val query = ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Comments")
        query.setLimit(limit)
        query.setSkip(skip)
        query.whereEqualTo("groupName", postid)
        query.addDescendingOrder("point")
        query.include("commenter")
        query.findInBackground { objects, e ->

            for (i in objects) {

               samplArray.add(i)

            }
            completion(sampleArray)

        }
        return sampleArray
    }
```

If i made a syntax error. dont worry about the error. i didn't copy and paste.

Comment: you can make it extensions

Comment: This belongs to a code review section since your code is working and you need a refactoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object companion to hold the method, like shown here https://alexdunn.org/2018/01/30/android-kotlin-basics-static-classes/

Instead of using the "create" method, you could have a Query class with the queryComment method inside the companion object so you could call it statically.

```
class Query() {
    companion object {
        fun queryComment (/*your arguments here*/): /*your result type here*/ {
           // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! now i can use this everywhere! ha! hey just one clarification, Will i have memory issue for keep using this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two option

1. **Create Extension function** [[Link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)]

> Extension function ability to extend a class with new functionality
>   without having to inherit from the class. To declare an extension function, we need to prefix its name with a receiver type.
>   E.x

```
    fun Context.showInfoDialog()
    {
       ....
    }

In your activity call showInfoDialog() fun
```

2. **Create Class and add static methods into this class**. (companion object in kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to put such a function inside a class's companion object, as shown in another answer.

But that's not strictly necessary; you can call a top-level function from anywhere, too.  It's easiest if you put it inside a package:

```
package myPackage

fun myFunction(…) { … }
```

Then you can call it as:

```
myPackage.myFunction(…)
```

Or you can import it:

```
import myPackage.myFunction

myFunction(…)
```

By the way, it's usually better to return an interface type (e.g. `List`) instead of the concrete implementation type (e.g. `ArrayList`), as that lets you change the implementation type without altering the rest of your code.  And you can avoid the loop by using `sampleArray.addAll(objects)`.  (There may be ways of avoiding copying the list at all, but I don't know the ParseQuery library you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass a reference to your function you may use reflecttion. To simplify an example imagine that in the following `f` is your `queryComment` and we want to pass around it's reference :

```
fun f (x : Int) : String = (x+1).toString()

fun ff( x: Int, block : (Int) -> String) {
    println(block(x))
}


fun main() {
    ff(1, ::f) // prints: 2
}
```